# C# How to change MenuItem's text in the OnClick

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am trying to change the text of a `MenuItem` inside a `ContextMenu`. I thought I have done this before, but I cannot remember.

Here is what I have:

```
private void TrayIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((MenuItem)sender).Text);
            if(((MenuItem)sender).Text.Equals("Pause"))
            { 
                icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Text = "Unpause";
                shouldPause = true;
            }

            if(((MenuItem)sender).Text.Equals("Unpause"))
            {
                icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Text = "Pause";
                shouldPause = false;
            }

            if(((MenuItem)sender).Text.Equals("Exit"))
            {
                icon.Visible = false;
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

When I try to change "Pause" to "Unpause" it doesn't work. However, if I try to change "Pause" to "Pizza", it actually works.. What the heck..

Thanks all!

EDIT:

Changed my code to the following:

```
private void TrayIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(((MenuItem)sender).Text.Equals("Pause"))
            {
                shouldPause = true;
            }

            if(((MenuItem)sender).Text.Equals("Unpause"))
            {
                shouldPause = false;
            }

            if(((MenuItem)sender).Text.Equals("Exit"))
            {
                icon.Visible = false;
                Application.Exit();
            }
            string text = "Pause";

            if(shouldPause)
            {
                text = "Unpause";
            }
            icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Text = text;
        }
```

And now it works.

Was it because I was trying to change the text on the item too soon after being clicked?

Comment: Add `else`: `if (...("Pause")) { ...} else if (...("Unpause")) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks! I are idiot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your observation, I am assuming that `icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0]` and `(MenuItem)sender` are the same menu item.

That would explain why it didn’t work with your first code:

```
if(((MenuItem)sender).Text.Equals("Pause"))
{ 
    icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Text = "Unpause";
    shouldPause = true;
}

if(((MenuItem)sender).Text.Equals("Unpause"))
{
    icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Text = "Pause";
    shouldPause = false;
}
```

The problem becomes a bit more clear when you introduce local variables:

```
var senderItem = (MenuItem)sender;
var firstItem = icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0];

if(senderItem.Text.Equals("Pause"))
{ 
    firstItem.Text = "Unpause";
    shouldPause = true;
}

if(senderItem.Text.Equals("Unpause"))
{
    firstItem.Text = "Pause";
    shouldPause = false;
}
```

If now `senderItem` and `firstItem` are the same, then what this code does is the following:

1. Check if the text is `Pause`
2. Change the text to `Unpause`
3. Set `shouldPause` to true
4. Check if the text is `Unpause`
5. Change the text to `Pause`
6. Set `shouldPause` to false

So basically, since these are separate `if`s, they *both* run, with the second overwriting the first.

You can generally avoid this by using `else if` instead of multiple separate/unliked `if`:

```
if(senderItem.Text.Equals("Pause"))
{ 
    firstItem.Text = "Unpause";
    shouldPause = true;
}
else if(senderItem.Text.Equals("Unpause"))
{
    firstItem.Text = "Pause";
    shouldPause = false;
}
```

Now, only one of those branches will ever run.

Comment: @Seth Don’t worry, mistakes like that happen all the time, so don’t feel bad about it! ;)